# .htaccess Redirect domain subdomain to sub directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

We'd like to redirect a subdomain to a subdirectory:

customerservice.example.com to example.com/customerservice.

How is this done in .htaccess file?

I assumed:

Redirect 301 customerservice.example.com example.com/customerservice

Am i correct in my assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirect does not take a full domain as first argument, you have to use `/`:

```
Redirect 301 / http://example.com/customerservice
```

However if this domain is on the same root of another domain and you need to match the domain name you will have to use something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^customerservice\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/customerservice/$1 [R=301,L]
```